# How can i Get back source data of data contained in a script PHP with Java

Tags: java, php, sqlite

I explain, I tried to open my database .sqlite contained in my server in Java with jdbc:sqlite:mydb, but it doesn't work because my database ".sqlite" is distant so i creat a script php based on my server which gets back me all of my databases.

So my question How can i Get back source data of data contained in a script PHP with Java?

Thanks a lot!

PS : Sorry for my english (I'm french)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a service in PHP which offers the data, so that your Java application can consume it.

E.g. PHP can expose the data in an XML or JSON format, for instance over HTTP. Your Java application would then call the HTTP URL and receive the data in JSON/XML/whatever, and then parse it to extract the data from that format.

There are other ways as well, e.g. a service bus could broker the data between the different systems, but that requires much more setup (though in the long run, it does have value, if you keep adding data that you want to expose to more and more systems).

Answer (score 0):

You can create PHP WebService server and write some functions to operate that databases data for fixing your problems. Then just use Java to connect with soap to your created WebService functions.

How to start webservice, try to read this one:
http://greatgandhi.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/create-a-php-webservice-in-5min-using-php-soap-and-wsdl-technology-nusoap/

Its the best way i know, if you need to send some data back to your remote db. Its a little more complicated, but much more correct way to operate remote data.